# How to prevent one username to complete the survey more than once with PHP & MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I've made a simple survey. Successfully filling and put it into a database table. Now the problem is how to prevent the username complete the survey more than once? Username is taken from the session. I've tried my own code here, but it didn't work :

```
<?php 
session_start();
include_once('config.php');

$username       = $_SESSION['username'];
$ask1           = $_POST['ask1'];
$ask2           = $_POST['ask2'];
$ask3           = $_POST['ask3'];
$ask4           = $_POST['ask4'];

$query = mysql_query("insert into survey values('', '$username', '$ask1', '$ask2', '$ask3', '$ask4')"); 


if ($query) {
        // success
        echo" <script language='JavaScript'> alert ('Thankyou for your participation');</script>";
        echo '<script language="JavaScript"> window.location.href ="home.php";</script>';
} else {
    echo "SELECT username FROM survey WHERE username='".$_SESSION['username']."'";
    $dup = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM survey WHERE username='".$_SESSION['username']."'");
        if(mysql_num_rows($dup) >0){
            echo"<script language='JavaScript'> alert ('You've filled out the survey!');</script>";
        echo '<script language="JavaScript"> window.location.href ="home.php" </script>';
        } else {
    // fail
     echo" <script language= 'JavaScript'> alert ('Failed to complete the survey'); </script>";
     echo '<script language="JavaScript"> window.location.href ="survey.php";</script>';
}}
?>
```

so what is the best solution for the problem like this? Thankyou in advance for you who want to help me. Thankyou once again.

Comment: @LorenzMeyer user with same username still can fill the survey

Comment: This code has SQL injection vulnerabilities, so duplicate surveys are the least of your problems.

Comment: Just make a unique key on (username,survey_id)... and see normalization (in addition to halfer's remarks above)

Answer (score 0):

In your code the problem is in the logic : You insert the new row and check afterwards if there is a row with the current username. Obviously you have to check first.

You show the code when you are saving the result of the survey. But in fact, you should check twice.

1. Before you display the form to the user, you have to check if he already filled it before.
2. Upon saving : not only test in PHP if there isn't a double. Define a unique index on the column username in your table, and you are guaranteed to never have a duplicate, even if your checks failed.

This is how to create a unique index :

```
alter table survey add unique index (username);
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but you didn't give the example. Honestly, I've already search the references, but didn't find it yet, because the references all said just give a unique index on the column. Just like that.

Comment: @user3528526: what remains unclear? Did you try adding a unique index on the user column?

Comment: Even if you check first and then insert, there's still the risk that a user can get multiple records inserted. If you do not want that possibility, you need to use unique constraints in the database.

Comment: Yes. 'Checking first' is unnecessary

Comment: @Strawberry For the database, a unique constraint is enough, there's no need to check first. You can always check if the query failed while inserting. But for the user experience, it is necessary to check even before displaying the form.